# Can I invite specific user to answer my question?

Tags: support

I am new to CV, but really like some user's answer; Can I invite certain users to answer my question? (Other users still can answer, but I want to show a special message to certain user.)

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism for that, but you can draw user's attention  by commenting under one of their answers. Try to choose an answer that you like and that is related to the Q you are asking; then you can comment something like `+1, I really liked this answer. I have asked a related question here <LINK> and would be really happy to see your answer there.` Alternatively, if this user is using chat, you can ping them in chat. Many people never used chat though, and then they will not receive your ping.

Comment: @amoeba That method can backfire.  Active users are likely already to have seen the question. Imploring them to take a look at it is (at best) an annoyance and may have the opposite of the intended response.  That is one of many reasons the site limits free-form interaction and controls the tools that allow it.  (For instance, moderators can ping anybody into a chat room, whether or not they have ever used chat.)

Comment: @whuber I agree. One should do something like that only with hesitation and with full understanding that this can be seen as annoyance. But I did use this method once or twice myself and it worked well.

Comment: @amoeba, In some Chinese version of the CV, people can invite a specific person to answer. Seems we do not have that.

Comment: There is a Chinese version of CV? Is it good?

Comment: @amoeba not CV per say but a general Q and A platform. In there people asking not so good questions but get excellent answers..

Comment: It's not part of the StackExchange model (the idea is you get to post questions, and any people who have both the time and the inclination get to post answers) -- and I think that absence of the ability to directly ask an individual to answer happens with good reason. Occasionally I get people nudge me for an answer (either in some other thread or via chat) on a particular question but unless there's a very specific reason - such as it's a follow on question to one I answered, for example - then I usually don't like to be prompted in this manner. ... ctd

Comment: (ctd) ... I don't mind people pointing out (say in chat) that they've asked a question they'd like me to read, perhaps because it's a topic I have expressed interest in (though there's a reasonable chance I will have seen it anyway), but I generally dislike the implied obligation in a request to answer.

Comment: @Glen_b I totally agree with you and know what a high reputation user would feel. (some questions are low quality and asked again and again without prior search) However, sometimes when I read some really awesome answer and the way the person answer it. I really want directly talk to the user because I know my question will be good and the user will like my question and will answer it perfectly. Is that possible that we have some limits on this behavior, say,  you can only direct contact a person 1 times a week?

Comment: There's a [feature-request](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info) tag for new feature requests.  Bear in mind you'd be asking Stack Exchange Inc to invest time & money in implementing a new feature, & that they don't seem keen to do anything further in that direction (see e.g [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/225179)). (For what it's worth I tend to agree with the reasons against doing so.) Consider @amoeba's suggestions.